# MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying to scrape addresses and Phone numbers from google for different business names, my code works fine when I give a URL, it fetches the required info. But when I tried to loop I'm getting the below error.

```
 MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
```

but the same URL works fine as shown below!

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=goinggourmet'
response = requests.get(url, {"User-Agent": ua.random})
print(Address)
```

This is code that raised an error while looping

```
bus_name = ['go', 'Copper']
for names in bus:
    html= urllib.parse.quote_plus(names)
    for url in google_urls:
        response = requests.get(url, {"User-Agent": ua.random})
```

Comment: `for url in google_urls` -- `google_urls` is a string. Treat it as a sequence, and you get one character of that string at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you create `google_urls` as a string before iterating, the `for` loop iterates over the characters in it instead

```py
>>> for value in "http":  # iterates over characters
...     print(value)
...
h
t
t
p
```

```py
>>> for value in ["http"]:  # iterates over a list with 1 member
...     print(value)
...
http
```

Comment: How do you reckon I can tweak it, So the first loop is obviously going to return strings. So how can I iterate through each link?

Comment: no need to iterate twice, I think! just iterate over the names, creating the url with them and you're good to go